# Как следует писать кавычки?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, термины, стиль

Коллеги, что вы считаете, следует ли в переводе интерфейса сайта отказаться от "знаков дюйма" и перейти на традиционные «ёлочки»?

Как мне кажется, «ёлочки», конечно, правильнее, но их тяжело набирать. Но всё же, это ведь строки официального перевода, который делается всего один раз.

Сейчас в Transifex используется как один, так и второй вариант.

Comment: Если уж речь зашла о знаке дюйма, то косые двойные кавычки лишь похожи на него.
По-настоящему дюйм передаётся знаком двойного штриха **″**

Comment: Ага, спасибо ) А то режет глаз дыра в статистике.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Это стандарт русского языка. Если сайт переводится, то нужно переводить его целиком, включая нормы пунктуации.

Из Википедии:

> В русском языке традиционно применяются французские «ёлочки», а для кавычек внутри кавычек и при письме от руки — немецкие «лапки». Кроме того, при переводе значения иноязычного слова иногда также употребляют английские одиночные (или так называемые марровские) кавычки (‘ ’): например, англ. reader — ‘читатель’.
>
> Правильно:
>
> > «„Цыганы“ мои не продаются вовсе», — сетовал Пушкин.

#### Как набрать этот символ на клавиатуре:

**Windows**: используем [Alt-код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4). Включить Num Lock, набирать на цифровой клавиатуре

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0171</kbd> = `«`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0187</kbd> = `»`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0132</kbd> = `„`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0147</kbd> = `“`

**OS X:**

Раскладки **U.S.**, **British**:

- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> = `«`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> = `»`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> = `„`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> = `“`

**Russian**

- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> = `«`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> = `»`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> = `„`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> = `“`

**Russian – PC**

- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Ъ</kbd> = `«`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>Ъ</kbd> = `»`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>Щ</kbd> = `„`
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd><kbd>Х</kbd> = `“`

**GNU/LInux:** (хотя, скорее, не для операционной системы, а для программы *xserver*) определить <kbd>Compose key</kbd> в настройках клавиатуры, все клавиши нажимаются последовательно, по одной

- <kbd>Compose key</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd><</kbd> = `«`
- <kbd>Compose key</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd> = `»`
- <kbd>Compose key</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> = `„`
- <kbd>Compose key</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> = `„`
- <kbd>Compose key</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> = `“`
- <kbd>Compose key</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd><</kbd> = `“`

Comment: и, при необходимости вложения, «„лапки“».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: спасибо, включил в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за хинт по набору елочек на Маке!

Comment: @SergeySnegirev: пожалуйста! Обратите внимание еще на раскладку US-Extended и функцию Show Keyboard Viewer.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, на русской раскладке Alt+] и Alt+Shift+] соответственно.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev: скопипастил, забыл поправить. )) Кстати, еще есть вот такая интересная раскладка: http://ilyabirman.ru/projects/typography-layout/

Comment: А меня в школе учили использовать польский вариант...

Comment: @PavelMayorov а это как?

Comment: @NickVolynkin „вот так”

Comment: Сейчас мне немецкий вариант видеть дико, он так неаккуратно торчит во все стороны... Но погуглил и вижу что именно он используется повсеместно, а польскому варианту, видимо, учили меня одного...

Comment: @PavelMayorov подумал, что в школе ведь совершенно не учат обращению с печатным текстом, в том числе типографике и основам верстки. А потом люди ставят пробелы перед знаками препинания и прочие непотребства творят...

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну почему же, пробелы и в рукописном тексте есть. Меня вот еще в начальной школе учили что перед большинством знаков препинания пробелы ставить не следует.

Answer (score 5):

Расставил «ёлочки» во всех переводах в Транзифексе.

В паре мест пришлось использовать „лапки“, но текст в этом месте выглядит подозрительно:

> You've reached the maximum of $dailyAllowedVotes$ Vote Down votes per day; come back $todayEnd$ → Вы достигли максимального суточного значения голосов за «Голосование „против“» — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$

*голосов за «Голосование „против“»?*

([Ссылка](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262948?qt=%E2%80%9E) для тех, у кого есть логин в транзифекс.)

Comment: Предлагаю их вот так заменить: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/672/181472

Comment: Насколько я помню из типографики, данное использование двух сортов кавычек нормально.

Comment: @KromStern: Проблема не в двух сортах кавычек, а в смысле фразы. Голоса за голосование — нонсенс.