# Создать рекомендации по оформлению ответов и вопросов

Tags: предложение, вопросы, ответы, стиль

Предлагаю в выпадающее меню справки, которая находится справа от пункта «очередь проверок», добавить новый пункт: «Рекомендации по оформлению».

Данная страница будет содержать рекомендации по оформлению ответов и вопросов, которые составит сообщество русскоязычного Stack Overflow. Чтобы привлечь пользователей к ознакомлению с рекомендациями, можно ввести бронзовый знак, который будет даваться за полное прочтение страницы (аналогично знаку «Информированный», что дается за «[Тур](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tour)»).

Мне кажется, что в данном направлении (не обязательно даже в формате нового пункта справки) надо сделать хоть что-нибудь, чтобы выработать в сообществе единый стиль оформления. Например, есть хороший вопрос с не менее хорошим ответом «[Как отправить голосовое сообщение через VK API?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609941/212210)», который наверняка будет вылезать первым в поиске на эту тему, потому что там описывается применение новой и не задокументированной возможности VK API. Но как по мне, благодаря не самому удачному оформлению читать эту стену текста не очень приятно.

Помимо насущных вещей, в данный трактат я также предлагаю добавить неоднозначные моменты в оформлении ответов:

- Как оформлять имена файлов? `index.php`, **index.php**, *index.php* или просто index.php?
- Как оформлять названия клавиш? Вместо `Enter` писать <kbd>Enter</kbd> и просить не использовать тег `<kbd>` для чего-то ещё.
- Рекомендации по обрамлению имён функций, методов и т.п. ссылками, указывающими на документацию на официальном или авторитетном ресурсе. Например, вместо **file_get_contents()** и `file_get_contents()` рекомендовать писать [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php).
- Рекомендации по использованию кавычек-«ёлочек» вместо "классических", а также длинных тире (`&mdash;` — наше всё) вместо дефисов. Было бы еще очень круто, если бы над полем ввода были 2 дополнительные кнопочки, при нажатии на которые в поле ввода подставлялись бы эти самые кавычки и тире.

Разумеется, эти рекомендации не должны быть обязательными и вряд ли новые пользователи ресурса охотно будут следовать им. Но люди, которые любят писать много текста в ответах, а также те, кому импонирует идея создания из ruSO базы данных ответов на вопросы, смогут определиться с единым стилем, от чего всё будет чистенько и аккуратненько.

Comment: `длинных тире (&mdash; — наше всё) вместо дефисов` — тут главное не переборщить, нужны и тире, и дефисы.

Comment: Люди, которые тут часто находятся и так обладают пониманием "Как правильно", а новички... ну это больная тема, 95% забьют на правила, логику, здравый смысл и огромную кнопку с надписью "Как надо". Остальные быстро сами научатся.

Comment: Возрождаем тему: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5158/181472

Answer (score 6):

Мне более интересны были бы рекомендации по **содержанию** вопросов и ответов:

- Как информацию структурировать, чтобы читатель лучше её воспринимал.
- Как сделать хорошие иллюстрации, схемы, диаграммы.
- Как хорошо сформулировать заголовки.
- Как правильно вводить термины. Вообще про понятийный граф. (Об этом я немного могу рассказать.)
- Как написать сеошный заголовок вопроса, чтобы у него были десятки тысяч просмотров.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендации по оформлению и многое другое уже публиковалось в нашем общественном [FAQ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/983).

- Про имена файлов, код и хоткеи - отличный ответ от [NickVolynkin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin): [Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328)
- Про кавычки (изначально относилось к локализации, но правила для языка - одни): [Как следует писать кавычки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/493)

Если там чего-то не хватает, всегда можно освежить информацию.