# Вложенные кавычки в описании достижения

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Предлагаю изменить тип кавычек в описании достижения, чтобы не было повторения:

> Вы заработали привилегию **«голосовать «за»»**! Узнать об этом больше можно в Справке.

> [image: скриншот текста достижения]

Хотя не знаю, может как сейчас тоже нормально...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласно [ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/498/176217) сделал вложенные кавычки-лапки [в этой строке](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265939?key=2f28efaad4e5d55b7fa9f0b2dc0f1874):

> голосовать „за“

Будем надеяться, что в других контекстах эта подстрока не используется. Если что-то заметите - пишите.

Как обычно, будет на сайте после подгрузки transifex и пересборки движка. Т.е. не раньше понедельника.

Comment: Наверняка используется ещё в описании привилегии, без внешних кавычек. :-\

Comment: @VladD если Вы об [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), то тут нет кавычек вовсе.

Comment: Хм. А в профиле?

Comment: @VladD там `голос «за»`, насколько я вижу. В общем, если найдёте конкретный случай - дайте знать.